# Will Azure automatically deduct money from my debit card?

Tags: azure, payment, billing

I forgot to delete/detach the storage and network groups and when i open my cost + billings after long days...now my bill gets 1,165 INR . I don't have that much money and i cannot able to detach my debit card but i canceled my pay as you go subscription but azure will automatically deduct money from my bank within 2 days. They send me the bill today. What can i do now so that azure cannot take money from my account. I don't want to pay money for the service which i don't used

I want that azure don't deduct my money from my debit card

Answer (score 0):

Open an Azure support request and explain your case.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request